# Caching codeigniter page on multilingual page

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I have a multilingual page with codeigniter 3.0 and I need cache whole pages. But if user change language I need make new cache for that language (not delete the old one).. I know about caching query string, but it is not pretty for me.

What I want to do is after change language set session and make new cache file. I tried change code in Output.php like this:

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['language']) && ! empty($_SESSION['language']))
    {
        $uri .= '?'.$_SESSION['language'];
    }
```

which should add language to uri if language is set (i did the same in display_cache function) .. but I get error about session_start(). I tried but it there, but then i get error in Session.php

How can I do that? Some hook or what? Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Have you use codeigniter and where you load session library???

Comment: I tried to do that with session library loaded in auto_load (configuration), but in Output class it doesn't know this. That's the reason why I use $_SESSION

Comment: are you using codeigniter 3??Also show the code of load session library

Answer (score 0):

*Edit the function _write_cache() in Output.php like this ->*

*add*

```
$lang = $CI->session->userdata('language');
```

*after of*

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

*and edit the ->*

```
$cache_path .= md5($uri);
```

*to*

```
$cache_path .= md5($uri).'-'.$lang;
```